# Preparing Time Capsule for shipping

Tags: time-capsule

I am moving, and I have an AirPort Time Capsule (3TB), which has a magnetic disk drive. Is there anything special I need to do to park the disk so it won't be damaged during shipping?

It will be in a box, along with other items, that's being shipped via air. I will make sure that it's physically protected (bubble wrap, etc.) to minimize the bumps.

But as far as I can tell, there's not even any way to turn it off, other than by pulling the plug.

Comment: What do the instructions say?

Comment: Modern hard drives have automatically parked the heads when powered down for years now. What you describe should be sufficient in packing the device for shipping.

Comment: @SolarMike Nothing useful: "Your AirPort Time Capsule may be damaged by improper storage or handling. Be careful not to drop your AirPort Time Capsule when transporting it." And: "There is no power switch."

Comment: @SteveChambers I assumed that was the case, but wanted to be sure. Guess I'll wrap it up the best I can and hope for the best.

Comment: Why not take it in your hand luggage?

Comment: To follow up: I wrapped some foam around it, and buried it deep in a box containing clothing. It survived unscathed. (I could not put it in hand luggage because I was moving from the US to Sweden, and had too much stuff to carry as it was).